# How to disable 'Changes you made may not be saved' when clicking an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, asp.net-mvc

I have a site built with Asp.Net mvc where I show a list of products and automatically fill in the default purchasing amount for those products in each corresponding input field.

However when i navigate to a different product catalog using the anchor tag the 'Changes may not be saved' alert pops up presumably because of the default values entered in the input fields.

Now I have tried to disable this alert using the following in my shared layout page inside of a script tag:

- window.onbeforeunload = null
- window.beforeunload = null

I have also tried various answers from similar questions but nothing seems to help.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this alert?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That alert is not automatic, it comes from your own code.

Comment: This seems to have been the problem, apparantly a directive was added by a colleague to throw this alert.

Answer (score 3):

You may have more success using this for jQuery:

```
$(window).off('beforeunload');
```

You can also read about some of the caveats and potential pitfalls of the `beforeunload` event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event).

#### Update:

Just to clarify a point further from a comment @Jamiec left, the event should be triggered in your project somewhere, try searching for `beforeunload` to see where it originates.

Comment: Added this to my shared layout but the alert still appears.

Comment: The above would only work if the event was bound using jQuery. If it's a native event use [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). You will need to find the event handler in your code to get a reference to it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery Try below code.

```
$(window).off('beforeunload');
```

This is best option for changes that you made may not be saved popup.

If you use javascript then you can use below code,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {return null;};
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly the alert was being called from a directive created by a colleague, by disabling this directive the alert no longer appears.

Thanks to Jamiec for notifying me.